# I want to SUM my GPA point Column And Then I want to Division full summation with rows

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I want to SUM my GPA point Column And  Then I want to Division full summation with  rows, from database according to my column (Class=Secession=roll).
Then I will echo full Grade. 
Please expert brother Help me. 
I am still learner. 
Thank You to all

[this is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6QsG.png)

```
<?php  
        include 'connect.php';
        $class_n =$_POST['class_n'];
        $class_s =$_POST['class_s'];
        $r =$_POST['roll'];

        $sql="select SUM(point) AS gpa from full_result where class_n='$class_n' AND class_s='$class_s' AND roll='$r'";
        $data = mysql_query($sql);
        $c = $gpa / 5;
        echo $c;
?>
```

Comment: $data = mysql_query($sql);
After this line I am not sure what will be. How can I show after sum, then How I division dynamically with rows,

Comment: Can you show us the desired output from this query?  What are you currently getting?

Comment: Yes, 
Notice: Undefined variable: gpa in F:\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\school\show_data.php on line 62
0

Comment: I attached as image my database. You may see

Comment: Please review the answer given below, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract out the `gpa` alias from your result set.  In the original problem, you were using the variable `$gpa` which was never assigned.

```
$sql="select SUM(point) AS gpa from full_result where class_n='$class_n' AND class_s='$class_s' AND roll='$r'";
$data = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
$gpa = $row["gpa"];
$c = $gpa / 5;
echo $c;
```

Comment: Thank You sir.! but it's not working properly, result only ( 0 ). And pls help me how I show the dynamically division with the sum rows. and will show the exact division result.  
Please sir Help.

Comment: Can you run the raw SQL query directly against your database?